# Is it possible to add spring/jiggle physics to a rigify metarig?

Tags: rigging, bones, physics, rigify

As the title says. I have found plenty of addons to do spring physics for bones.

But all the ones I tried rely on custom properties that wouldn't carry over through the rig generation, and I could add those properties to the generated rig, but it being a much more complicated one and losing the ability to re-generate the rig if I want to add more things to it afterwards is a drawback.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't actually find an answer to my own question but did find a workaround, so I am posting in case it shows in search results.

Basically, while applying the addons to the bones in the metarig don't work as far as I see, you can apply it to the drivers in the generated rig and those do survive a regeneration of the rig.

I found that works best to apply it on rig types for single bones (like `basic.super_copy` or `basic.raw_copy`) or bone chains controlled in a FK fashion (like `basic.copy_chain`)

Comment: Interesting workaround. I am actually not sure how you add the Jiggle physics in Drivers but good job finding a way that works!